# Replace string in a file with a specific field value from another file with awk

Tags: awk, replace

My file1 looks like:

```
bla bla bla STRING_1 blabla STRING_2.
bla bla bla bla bla.
```

My file2 looks like (tab-separated):

```
FILENAME   FIELD_1   FIELD_2
out1   ABCDEF   GHIJKL
out2   MNOPQR   STUVWX
```

I am trying to replace `STRING_1` and `STRING_2` from file1 with the corresponding fields from file2, and output 2 different files with their name as below:

out1:

```
bla bla bla ABCDEF blabla GHIJKL.
bla bla bla bla bla.
```

out2:

```
bla bla bla MNOPQR blabla STUVWX.
bla bla bla bla bla.
```

What I tried:

```
awk -F '\t' '
NR==FNR{
   if(NR>1){
      a[NR]=$1
      b[NR]=$2
      c[NR]=$3
      next
   }
}
{
   for(i=1; i<=FNR; i++){
      gsub(/STRING_1/,bi])
      gsub(/STRING_2/,c[i])
      print $0 > a[i]
   }
}
' file2.tab file1.tab
```

This command only creates a file "FILENAME" that contains the following:

```
bla bla bla FIELD_1 blabla FIELD_2.
bla bla bla bla bla.
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks !

NOTE: file1 is a unique template file for which the content does not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ 
         if (NR==1) next;
         c=0; f[$1][++c]=$2; f[$1][++c]=$3; next 
     }
     { 
         c=0;
         for (i in f) { 
             b[++c]=$0; 
             gsub(/STRING_1/, f[i][1], b[c]); 
             gsub(/STRING_2/, f[i][2], b[c]); 
             print b[c] > i 
         }
     }' file2 file1
```

- `f[$1][++c]` - multidimensional array `f` where `$1` is a parent key (for ex. `out1`) and `++c` points to ordinal field number (i.e. `1` and `2`)
- `for (i in f)` - iterating through output *filenames*

Viewing results:

```
$ head out[12]
==> out1 <==
bla bla bla ABCDEF blabla GHIJKL.
bla bla bla bla bla.

==> out2 <==
bla bla bla MNOPQR blabla STUVWX.
bla bla bla bla bla.
```

Comment: @EdMorton, try without it and you'll see

Comment: No, that's fine, I don;t care enough to try it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to implement your approach of using gsub()s, untested:

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
    if (NR>1) {
        files[$1]
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
            map[$1,i-1] = $i
        }
    }
    next
}
{
    for (file in files) {
        rec = $0
        gsub(/STRING_1/,map[file,1],rec)
        gsub(/STRING_2/,map[file,2],rec)
        print rec > file
    }
}
' file2 file2
```

Note that this approach will have problems if STRING_1, etc. can contain regexp metacharacters, or if the replacement ones can contain backreferences (`&`), or if partial matches are possible (`the` replaced within `then`). You may also need to close() the output files as you go and use `>>` to write to them if you have many output files and aren't using GNU awk.